# Alamofire InvalidURL in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

im trying to get data from api using alamofire and it giving me 
invaildURL("http://tdlly.com/Api/Advertisements/1/18") 
i tried to encode url but also not working that's my code

```
 class func nearAds(completion: @escaping(_ error: Error?, _ data:[Ad]?)->Void) {
    let url = URLs.nearAds+"\(helper.getApiToken())"
    //let s  = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default , headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result
        {
        case.failure(let error):
            completion(error,nil)
            print("error for nearAds",error)
        case.success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            print("near,\(json)")
            guard let dataArr = json.array else{
                completion(nil , nil)
                return
            }
            var ads = [Ad]()
            for data in dataArr {
                if let data = data.dictionary ,let result = Ad.init(dic: data) {
                    ads.append(result)
                }
            }
            completion(nil,ads)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the return value of helper.getApiToken() an optional? If so, your url string will consist of "Optional("")".

Comment: @koropok i save the token from login json at userDefaults  and return it by this func  class func getApiToken() -> Int {
        let def = UserDefaults.standard
        return (def.object(forKey: "user_id") as! Int)
    }

Comment: i ran your URL on alamofire and it seems to be working. can you do a print on your url?

Comment: @koropok http://tdlly.com/Api/Advertisements/1/18 that is the url with token id when i try it at postman its working but at xcode not working give me invaildURL

Comment: To debug your error, I'd make use of Postman. Throw a breakpoint in and type `po url` in the debugger. Then, in Postman, dump that url in from the debugger and see what the API kicks back.

Comment: @Adrian i did already that at postman and it's already work fine without any problem

Comment: @mahmoudAbdlAziz Whoever wrote that API returning all strings should be locked in a port-o-potty and lit on fire. That said, I'm able to hit that endpoint without the key method, which I presume is a string. Is the `helper.getApiToken()` an optional return? If so, you might want to unwrap the string from getApiToken before adding it to the end. What's `po url` print out if you throw a breakpoint into your method? If you can hit it in postman, it ought to be a valid url in the method, too.

Comment: @Adrian i get the token from login then save it to userdefaults after that i call it by this class func getApiToken() -> Int { let def = UserDefaults.standard return (def.object(forKey: "user_id") as! Int) }

Comment: @Adrian it i save just the num of user then return by that func to the url.but can u show me how to unwarp it safely ?

Comment: i will try it right now and tell u the result

Comment: @Adrian I tried ur way but give me this error    Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'

Comment: Post the method signature for `helper.getApiToken()`. I'm interested in what the return is. What you've posted tells me it's not optional. You've also indicated it's an Int. If it's an Int, you need to wrap it with `String(helper.getApiToken())`, so it would look like this: `URLs.nearAds+ String(helper.getApiToken())`. While we're at it, what does the declaration of `URLS.nearAds` look like? Is it an `enum`? If so, you might need to specify `.rawValue` on the end.

Comment: i did that by convert the int to string with diffrent ways and still not work. and i didnt understand what u meant at last part but if u talk about the struct to init data its class object using SwiftyJSON . BUT thats not the problem im sure its at the request method but idk how to fix hhh

Comment: The problem is your URL, so your problem likely lives in 1) `URLs.nearAds` and 2) `helper.getApiToken()`. You should post code for both of those declarations. Need to know what URL.nearAds looks like and what `helper.getApiToken()` returns.

Comment: @Adrian yeah i did that too but this api for ads and the logout only have this issue but for other apis works so perfect even at postman its work .please can you try my code and seeif it will work with u or not ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add http protocol to string.
so for e.g. you link will looks like `http://tdlly.com/Api/Advertisements/1/18`

if you already did so please show screenshot of debug print (po url) after line

```
let url = URLs.nearAds+"\(helper.getApiToken())"
```

and make sure that you enabled `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` in `Info.plist`

check here [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Comment: yes my friend.u will see above its already http:// protocol and yeah i already enabled transport security  this the message invaildURL("http://tdlly.com/Api/Advertisements/1/18")

Comment: Does your token contains `#` symbol?
Tell what's inside URLs.nearAds and show example of getApiToken() return value

Comment: what does `po url` prints in debug console?

Comment: as i told u above my friend invalidURL+the link above